# Get Result from Invoke Method from Action Delegate C#

Tags: c#, delegates, inversion-of-control

Is there a way to get the result from the invoke method in the generic action delegate?

**Code Execution**

```cs
public string TestRun()
{
   ExecuteService<SomeClass>(e => e.ExecuteMethod(), out var result);
   return result; // return the value;
}
```

**Class Method**

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public string ExecuteMethod()
    {
        return "Hello!?";
    }
}
```

**Method of executing a generic action delegate**

```cs
protected internal void ExecuteService<TAction>(Action<TAction> action, out Response response) where TAction : new()
{
    action?.Invoke(new TAction()); // invoke
    response = action?.something() // problem... how to get the value from this point forward
}
```

How to get the returned value from this method `ExecuteMethod()` inside the action delegate `ExecuteService<>` method and assigned it to the `out` value?  Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by not using an [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0). `Action`s in C# are a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) that return `void`, i.e nothing. If you need a return value from a delegate use either [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) or if you need it to specifically return a boolean use [`Predicate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-5.0). Like this:

```cs
protected internal void ExecuteService<TAction>(Func<TAction> action, out Response response)
{
    response = action?.Invoke();
}
```

If you need the inner the `action` to take parameters, use one of the other `Func` classes like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) one which takes 1 parameter and returns `T`

Comment: Hi I tried your solution but didn't work, it gave me an error in `?` at `action?.Invoke()`, also how can I inject my IoC in the invoke method?

Comment: Thanks for this I got the idea now, I change the return type of from `void` to `TOutput`.
`protected internal TOutput ExecuteService<TAction, TOuput>(Func<TAction, TOutput> action)`.  Your informative comments really helped me a lot. Thank you!